# Magento 2 product count in layer navigation for text swatches

Tags: magento-2.1, product, layered-navigation, swatches

I want to show the product count on layer navigation for text swatches.

By default Magento providing this feature for normal attributes(Text, Dropdown, and multi-select) in layer navigation but is not available for swatches.

Please see the below-attached screenshot for more clarity.

**I Want like below**

[image]

**Magento by default providing for another attribute like text, dropdown**

[image]

Please help on above issue.Any references or suggestions highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `\Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered::getOptionViewData`

You can modify option returning option data to

```
return [
    'label' => $swatchOption->getLabel(),
    'link' => $linkToOption,
    'custom_style' => $customStyle,
    'count' => $filterItem->getCount()
];
```

and render product count in `Magento/Swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml`

```
<?php foreach ($swatchData['options'] as $option => $label): ?>
    <?= $label['count']; ?>
```

---

Note, that you must not modify core module code. Instead that, you can use base ways to customizing module behavior (`plugins`, `layouts`, etc)